# How to manual trigger the touchesBegan value in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a parent viewcontroller , and there have a subview(UIView).

The subview(named xibSubView) is called other custom class(xib) file.

When I click on the parent Viewcontroller, the subview(UIView) will motion to touch began position on the parent viewcontroller.

The parent viewcontroller have

```
 // UIViewcontroller.h file
  .....    
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet XibSubView *xibSubView;
 .....
```

The below code is in the parent viewcontroller .m

```
 -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
    self.subViewConstraint.constant = touchLeftScreenPoint.x ;
    self.subViewConstraint.constant = touchLeftScreenPoint.y ;

 }

 -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 }

 -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 }
```

And the xib(subview-xibSubView) code have the same delegate method.

```
 // The code is in the parent viewcontroller .m
 -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 }

 -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 }

 -(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 }
```

In the xibSubView have much elements.

One of the elements will motion to the click position in the subview(xibSubView).

So I want to pass the parent viewcontroller touches into xibSubView.

And manual call the touchBegan in the xibSubView let the element motion.

So I should transform the parent viewcontroller touches  position to subview touches position.

The subview  touches x position and y position  will subtract the viewcontroller width and height and manual call the touchbegan method.

But I don't know how to changed the touches x, y values restore to touches.

Then call the code:

```
 [self.xibSubView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

How can I change the NSSet touches x,y variable and restore to touches.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Doing exactly this is hard. When redirecting events, it is usually done from subviews to superview not the other way around. This seems more like an architecture problem though. Usually you want only one view to handle touches and if you want to pass events to subviews, use custom methods (e.g. passing only the position). It will make the problem easier.

Comment: in fact, the subview is like joystick, so that have move self from user click subview. and I will click on the parent viewcontroller, the joystick will change the self view to touch postion, and It can move immediately.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "view.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
 view *v;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   v=[[view alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
   [self.view addSubview:v];
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [v touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

view.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view : UIView
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end
```

view.m

```
#import "view.h"

@implementation view

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  NSLog(@"%@",touches);
}
@end
```

Comment: this will trigger touch action in UIViewController to UIView.

Comment: or you can do the reverse, touch in UIView to UIViewController

Comment: My view coordinate was not same with parent viewcontroller, So in your case, ViewController's touchbegan method get touches variable will transform x,y coordinate(like substract touchesPoint.x ), then call [v touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; The problem is on I don't know when I transform the some value, How can I save to touches variable, then call [v touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141846/how-to-change-a-uitouchs-location-before-passing-to-the-next-responder

Comment: donot make conversions to uitouch, refer above link

Comment: But my case have move the subview to parent view touch position.and in the subview elements have to subtract offset value.because the [touch locationInView:view] the view is parent view not subview. @@

Comment: I got it!!! I change to [touch locationInView:self]. the coordinate is correct! thank you very much,@Britto Thomas.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSMutableArray *touchArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[touchArray addObject:[UITouch new]];
NSSet *touches = [[NSSet alloc] init];
[touches setByAddingObjectsFromArray:touchArray];
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];
```

**Swift**

```
let tArr = NSMutableArray()
tArr.add(UITouch())
let touch = NSSet()
touch.adding(tArr)

touchesBegan(touch as! Set<UITouch>, with: nil)
```

Comment: I have to transform the coordinates. The touches x, y  in the parent viewcontroller is different with subview. So how can I transform to touches value and restored to the NSSet, then  pass to the touchesBegan.

Comment: cant create a uitouch object programatically.

Comment: I know we can't create a uitouch object programmatically, so I want to get the touch value from the parent viewcontroller from user touch on the parent viewcontroller, then get the touches value to subtract some value , pass into the xibsubview touches Began.So How can I change the touches value and restore?thank you.

Comment: the xibSubView extends UIView,It's xib file.It was called about touch began when I touch on the subview.@@

Comment: suppose touch x position is substract parent viewcontroller x  position.How can I change the touches x value pass into the subview touchbegan. I know how to called subview touchbegan, but I don't know how to change the touches CGpoint value.